# Qual è il senso di "vincete" come un aggettivo?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel titolo di [questo articolo di Euronews](http://it.euronews.com/2017/08/31/giappone-africa-una-cooperazione-vincete/),

> Giappone-Africa: una cooperazione **vincete**

mi ha stupita l'uso della parola "vincete". Conosco questo vocabolo come seconda persona plurale del presente indicativo e imperativo del verbo "vincere", ma qui sembra si usi come un aggettivo. Ho cercato se si trova nei vocabolari, ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Sapreste spiegarmi quale senso ha?

Comment: Deve essere un refuso. Il termine corretto è **vincente**

Comment: Nessuno. È un chiaro refuso e dubito che la domanda possa essere utile in futuro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sicuramente è un refuso. Il termine corretto da usare è **vincente**:

> Giappone-Africa: una cooperazione **vincente**

Vincente è il participio presente del verbo vincere, numero singolare, usato qui come aggettivo.